# Page_Load Vs Page_InitComplete in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I've seen programmers writting in `Page_Load` like

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}
```

So that the codes will be worked only once.

If so, why don't we put that code in `Page_InitComplete`? Since `Page_InitComplete` is done only once.

What are the pros and cons by doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any advantage to what you're suggesting but I can see problems with it. For one thing, server controls do not yet have their data loaded during `InitComplete`. For another thing, code in this event executes regardless if whether or not it's a postback.

Use the `Load` event. That's what it's for. It only executes once per request. If you want to restrict code to only run on postbacks, or only run during non-postback requests, test `IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can answer your own question reading through the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). The `InitComplete` is triggered only once but on each post back just like the `Load` event.

Comment: +1 For referring to Page Life Cycle overview. Understanding this is fundamantal to doing business in ASP.NET.